# file_exists() works in apache root but not in subdirectory

Tags: php, elgg

I have installed ispconfig3. Ive added a website but when i try to install elgg in /var/www/clients/client1/web5/web/, it fails because `file_exists()` returns false when looking for the directory /var/www/clients/client1/web5/data/. When i check from a php file in the root, it finds the directory. I have changed all the permissions for the parent folders but ist still failing. Ispconfig3 uses symlink to link my domain to that directory, maybe thats causing the problem...

Comment: Does the symlink point outside the docroot? Are you using a tool such as [AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/). Any of these [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) tools can prevent an application from reading specific files, perhaps they aren't configured for your site. Check `dmesg(1)` output to see if there are any rejection messages, most or all these tools log to `dmesg(1)` if `auditd(8)` isn't running.

Comment: the symlink is pointing to the docroot which is at /var/www/clients/client1/web5/web/. i dont think im using any of those tools (im not familiar with ubuntu) but i disabled apparmor and still file_exists() is failing but working when placed in /var/www/

Comment: even when i create an uploads folder in /var/www/uploads, it still cannot find it..

Comment: i included php_admin_value open_basedir none in the vhost and that worked

Answer (score 0):

As written in the docs

> Warning. 
>   This function returns FALSE for files inaccessible due to safe mode restrictions. However these files still can be included if they are located in safe_mode_include_dir.

Comment: Safe mode is off and even when i add that directory is still fails. from the root though, it returns true...